# Convert zip to store compression in Unix

Tags: bash, unix, zip, compression

I have a zip file `file.zip` that is compressed to save space with the 9 (compress better) setting on the Unix zip command.

I considered manually extracting `file.zip` but I have hundreds of zips that I need to change.

What would be the easiest way to change the compression level of `file.zip` to 0 (store only) in a Unix system?

Comment: Extract and rearchive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

FILENAME=file.zip

TMP_DIR=$(mktemp -d "./XXXXX")
mkdir $TMP_DIR
unzip "$FILENAME" -d ./$TMP_DIR/
rm "$FILENAME"
cd $TMP_DIR
zip -0 -r "../$FILENAME" ./*
cd ..
rm -r $TMP_DIR
```

edit: Improve based on [Ignacio's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20862/ignacio-vazquez-abrams) comments.

Comment: That method of naming/creating the temporary directory is both racy and insecure.

Comment: You're right, it's possible there might already be an existing directory with same name or the filename would contain some risky string. But i'm not sure what is correct way of creating the temp directory. How would you improve it?

Comment: I would use `mktemp -d` on systems where it is available.

Comment: And don't forget the quoting. You can't control what filenames might be used.